# How to add special symbol to the regular expression to allow in text field?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which will allow only numbers 0-9.
But i want to allow -(hyphon) also.[- ASCII code is 45]
I tried it.. But no use.. Can you update my code?

```
 function isNumericKey(e)
        {
        if (window.event) { var charCode = window.event.keyCode; }
        else if (e) { var charCode = e.which; }
        else { return true; }
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) { return false; }
        return true;
    }
    function submitMyNumber()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
        return input.match(/^[0-9-]+$/) != null;
    }
```

`<form>
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" name="mySubmit" value="Submit My Number" onclick="return submitMyNumber();" />
</form></pre>`

Laxman Chowdary

Comment: So you want to accept numbers with -. right? Or can you please explain what all things you want your code to accept

Comment: I want to display date which can allow numbers and separator -(hyphon)..

Comment: why do you ``return true`` when you get no event? shouldn't ``return false`` ?

Comment: Hachi, This code is working fine for numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you filter the 45 charcode

```
 function isNumericKey(e)
        {
        if (window.event) { var charCode = window.event.keyCode; }
        else if (e) { var charCode = e.which; }
        else { return true; }
        if (charCode == 45 || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
```

Will work better.

Start with hyphen when you specify a range in your regular expressions.

```
 /^[-0-9]+$/
    ^-- here

 /^[0-9-]+$/
       ^--- does not work here
```

If you want to match a date the pattern is probably something like dd-dd-dd (but which format? ISO YYYY-MM-DD ? or something else)
A more correct pattern will be.

```
 /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

Probably this one is better

```
 /^[12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d$/
```

For the DD-MM-YYYY reverting the pattern is quite simple :

```
 /^[0-3]\d-[01]\d-[12]\d{3}$/
```

Comment: One more thing.. in function isNumericKey(e) we have not added 45.. So it is not allowing.. How to add it in condition?

Comment: how about escaping the hyphen? ``/^[0-9\-]+$/`` or since numbers only have a hyphen as first character this ``/^\-[0-9]+$/`` should be more useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept 29-06-2012 i.e. 2 digits hyphen 2 digits hyphen 4 digits which is date-pattern the regular expression is `[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}`

Comment: Hi Saurabh, To accept -(hyphon) we have to add a condition in isNumericKey(e) also ????